# How to get the user repo from github API using react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github-api

I have a react app that searches the github for users using github api. I have the part that searches for users working fine, but when I add in a component to display the user's repo as well, it just displays the user info only and the console gives this error: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined`

Here is my code:

```
    class GitHubSearch extends React.Component {
       constructor(props){ 
         super(props); 
          this.state = { 
           username: '',
           userrepo: '',
          };
       }

       getUser(username) {
          return fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${username}`)
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(response => {
            return response;
           })
      }

       getUserRepo(userrepo) {
         return fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${username}/repos`)
         .then(response => response.json())
         .then(response => {
          return response;
        })
      }

       async handleSubmit(e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           let user = await this.getUser(this.refs.username.value);
           this.setState({ avatar_url: user.avatar_url,
           username: user.login,
           followers: user.followers,
           following: user.following,
            url: user.url,
       });

     let repo = await this.getUserRepo(this.refs.userrepo.value);
        this.setState({ name: repo.name,
        description: repo.description,
        git_url: repo.git_url,
        stargazers_count: repo.stargazers_count,
        forks_count: repo.forks_count,
        open_issues_count: repo.open_issues_count,
        size: repo.size,

     })

  }

     render() {
       let user;
       if(this.state.username) {
          user = 
          <div className="resultBadge">
            <img src={this.state.avatar_url}/>
            <p className="userInfo">
             Username: <br/>
             {this.state.username} 
            </p> 
            <p className="followerInfo">
             {this.state.followers} Followers
            </p>
            <p className="followingInfo">
              Following {this.state.following} users
            </p>
          </div>
      }

      let repo;
        if(this.state.userrepo) {
           repo =
             <div className="repoResults">
                <p>
                  {this.state.name}
               </p>
             </div>
         }

           return (
              <div className="GitHubSearch">
                <header className="Search-header">
                  <h1>Github User Search </h1>
                </header>
                <form onSubmit={e => this.handleSubmit(e)}>
                   <input ref='username' type='text' placeholder='username' />
               </form>
               <p className="Search-intro">
                  {user}
               </p>
      <p>
        {repo}
       </p>
      </div>
   );
 }
}


ReactDOM.render(<GitHubSearch/>, document.getElementById('container'));
```

The HTML is:

Is there something missing here?

Comment: What does react have to do with this? And given that the error tells you exactly what's wrong, what exactly is your question?

Comment: Where is your `<input ref="userrepo">`?

Comment: @zero298 oops I can't believe I made that error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you don't have `userrepo` ref.

Probably, you should use the same ref to get repos because your `getUserRepo` gets username property and not name of repository.

So your `getUserRepo` function should looks like this:

```
let repo = await this.getUserRepo(this.refs.username.value);
        this.setState({ name: repo.name,
        description: repo.description,
        git_url: repo.git_url,
        stargazers_count: repo.stargazers_count,
        forks_count: repo.forks_count,
        open_issues_count: repo.open_issues_count,
        size: repo.size,

     })
```

Comment: Ok thanks. So can I do this? `<input ref='username userrepo' type='text' placeholder='username' />`

Comment: @MikeL5799 actually, you don't need to add separate input because  both functions `getUser` and `getUserRepo` expect the same value.

Comment: Oh no I wasn't adding a 2nd input, I was changing the input to have the 2 values in the same ref

Comment: @MikeL5799 what is the purpose of it? In both cases you just need `username` :) 

`https://api.github.com/users/${username}` - fetch user
`https://api.github.com/users/${username}/repos` - fetch user repos

Comment: @MikeL5799 Answering on your question - no. Each input field can have only one value.

Comment: Thanks. the repo info still doesn't show up. so weird.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169461/discussion-between-denys-kotsur-and-mikel5799).